# Java Applet is not loading on a Mac after update 1.6.0.33

Tags: java, macos, applet

After the latest java update my applet has stopped loading.  It appears that apple has fixed some applet security vulnerabilities and that is what is causing my applet to stop working.  My applet uses multiple signed jars and all have been signed correctly.  I have enabled applets to run in the java preferences and this didn't fix the issue either.

I'm thinking that the issue might be related to the location that I'm downloading the signed jars to.  Currently they are being saved in a hidden directory under:

$HOME/myapp/

and I think these jars need to be placed here.

$HOME/Library/Application Support/myapp/

Does anyone know if apple has any direction on where these files should be downloaded to and why?

Comment: *"I'm thinking that the issue might be related to the location that I'm downloading the signed jars to."*  I develop applets and don't know (or care) where they are downloaded to.  It should happen automatically - be 'invisible'.  Can you run other applets without worrying about where to download the files?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Which tag are you using to load the applet? I switched from `<object>` to `<applet>` and it seems to work, even though the applet tag is deprecated.